# открытие javaFX окна много раз

Tags: java, javafx

при нажатии на кнопку в у меня должно открыться javaFx окно. Первый раз открывается отлично, но после открытия окна 2 раз вылетает `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application launch must not be called more than once`. Я знаю откуда это ошибка, и что `launch();` можно вызвать только 1 раз. На форумах, где уже отвечали на подобный вопрос предлагают использовать `Platform.runLater(()->{});` только у меня вообще не получается это сделать. Мб кто-то сможет написать примерный псевдо код как это делать.  Все максимально просто: из первого окна при нажатии на кнопку должно вызывать второе окно, и главное что бы второе окно можно было вызвать много раз. Я не совсем понимаю что нужно вызвать в методе `Platform.runLater`: либо `start(new Stage());`, либо `launch();`, либо `primaryStage.show()`? Тока не минусуйте карму за возможно дубликат вопроса и тд. :3.    Заранее спасибо

Comment: что должно происходить с первым окном при открытии второго? второе окно модальное?

Comment: ну вообще, я могу просто запустить 2 окно в новом потоке (это точно могу уже пробывал) и оба окна будут работать паралельно, но если надо могу и все в 1 потоке сделать и тогда 2 окно будет модальным

Comment: UI обрабатывается в одном потоке. так что окна работают в одном потоке.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Скриншот результата]

**Main.java**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("FirstWindow.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

**FirstWindowController.java**

```
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class FirstWindowController implements Initializable{
    public Button btnOpenSecondWindow;
    public Label txtContent;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources){
        btnOpenSecondWindow.setOnAction(e -> {
            Parent root;
            try {
                FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("SecondWindow.fxml"));
                root = loader.load();

                Stage stage = new Stage();
                stage.setTitle("Second window");

                Scene scene = new Scene(root);
                stage.setScene(scene);
                stage.initOwner(btnOpenSecondWindow.getScene().getWindow());

                //SecondWindowController controller = loader.getController();
                //controller.someMethodCall();

                stage.showAndWait();
            } catch (Exception exc) {
                exc.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**SecondWindowController.java**

```
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class SecondWindowController implements Initializable{
    public Label txtContent;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources){
        //no-op
    }
}
```

**FirstWindow.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<VBox xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
      xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
      fx:controller="FirstWindowController"
      prefHeight="200.0"
      prefWidth="200.0">

    <Label fx:id="txtContent"
           text="I am the first window!"/>

    <Button fx:id="btnOpenSecondWindow"
            text="Open second"/>

</VBox>
```

**SecondWindow.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<Pane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
      xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
      fx:controller="SecondWindowController"
      prefHeight="150.0"
      prefWidth="150.0">

    <Label fx:id="txtContent"
           text="I am the SECOND window!"/>

</Pane>
```

**Структура проекта**

[image: Структура проекта]